# Conda importing one environment.yml into another

Tags: python, git-submodules, conda

Consider the situation where you're importing a Python submodule with dependencies into a project with its own dependencies. Say that the submodule has its `environment.yml` file and the project itself has an `environment.yml` file.

Is there a way to create an environment incorporating both of these environment specifications, and if so, how would you go about doing this? (Or is there a better/more preferred way to handle this situation?)

Answer (score 15):

I'm guessing you're the one developing both the submodule and the project since the dependencies are still in the `environment.yml` files.

#### Option 1: Update Project Environment using Submodule's environment.yml

This unfortunately might be your only option if your submodule has dependencies on `conda` packages.

```
# First create the project environment
$ conda env create --force -f project_environment.yml

# Then update with submodule dependencies
$ conda env update -n project-env-name --file submodule_environment.yml
```

This is less than ideal since the basic expectation is that your imported libraries come with their own dependencies.

#### Option 2: Put dependencies into respective requirements.txt files

This is applicable only if the submodule dependencies can be installed from PyPi via `pip`. First put the dependencies of the project and submodule into their respective `requirements.txt` files.

Then restructure the `environment.yml` files to look the following:

`submodule_environment.yml`

```
name: submodule-env-name
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.6.3             # no conda dependencies
- pip:
    - -r requirements.txt  # <--- submodule dependencies
```

`project_environment.yml`

```
name: project-env-name
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.6.3
- pip:
    - -r requirements.txt                    # <--- project dependencies
    - -r project/submodule/requirements.txt  # <--- submodule dependencies
```

In this way you can ignore the `submodule_environment.yml` file altogether and then create the project environment with a single command.

```
$ conda env create --force -f project_environment.yml
```

This approach will not work if your `submodule` has dependencies on `conda` packages. If it does then Option 1 is your best option.

#### Option 3: Package the Submodule (Ideal)

Assuming the submodule has no conda dependencies then it would be ideal to just make a separate package out of the submodule. Create a `setup.py` and put all the dependencies into the `install_requires` field. Here's a template of how the [setup.py](https://gist.github.com/nitred/0764bfd72087946cab7c477395b24734#file-template_setup-py) file should look like.

Once it's packaged, you can do the following:

- Install it locally using:

  - `pip install .`
- Upload to github or bitbucket and install it using:

  - `pip install git+https://github.com/username/submodule.git --upgrade`
- Upload to github or bitbucket and add the following to `requirements.txt` or `environment.yml` under `pip`:

  - `git+https://github.com/username/submodule.git#egg=submodule`

Comment: This is a great answer.  It illustrates things about conda packaging that I have not seen used anywhere else.  @nitred, do you have a reference to where you found how to do this?

Comment: [This](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) is my go to resource for managing conda environments. The day I read that is the last day I used venv or pipenv :) Also going through the `conda` CLI documentation fills in the gaps.

However Option 1 and especially Option 2 are non traditional use cases of managing environments. I would always recommend maintaining a single environment file and making sure your code is packaged via `setup.py`.

P.S. You can even do `pip install .` and `pip install -e .` from the environment file ;)

Comment: It's sad that with conda we need to resort to pip to install another package that already has a conda definition, one would have thought this would have been sorted out by now...

Comment: @kellpossible Not true, Option 1 does not depend on pip at all and both `project_environment.yml` and `submodule_environment.yml` files can exclusively have conda dependencies only. The OP has an unusual project structure which requires an unusual solution. Also the data-science packages have come a long way since 2018, most are fully supported on Pypi and are available via pip. If dependencies are available via pip, then they can be put into `setup.py` which makes them official and enforceable dependencies of the package.

Comment: @nitred That's true, you're right Option 1 does not depend on pip. It would still be nice if it didn't require extra command line arguments to facilitate, but rather the information about the relation to subprojects was captured in the environment.yml of the parent project. The second half of your reply though is suggesting that the need for using conda in the first place is less?

Comment: @kellpossible To answer the first part of your reply - If am not mistaken Python does not support sub-packages (i.e. a package within a package). Therefore structuring a project with sub-packages is going to introduce unnecessary steps just to make it work. The fact that `conda` lets you do it in the first place is a testament to its capabilities.

Comment: @kellpossible To answer your question - Yes, you don't need to download packages from `anaconda` and `conda-forge` too much any more these days. Keep in mind [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html) is a package & environment management tool and is different from [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/). It lets the user decide where to download packages from. I still use it to manage my environment, exactly like in Option 2 where all my dependencies are downloaded via `pip` but I am able give provide a name and python version to use for my environment.

Comment: @nitred Thanks for the information. In the end I decided to use `poetry` for this project because it better supports the use-case with the [path dependency](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies)