# How to define Anaconda env file when one of the dependencies has an env file in it already?

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, conda, environment

I have a project with a conda `environment.yml` file where one of the dependencies is a GitHub project that I'm referencing though it's URL and that project has its own `environment.yml` file.

**How can I tell conda to recursively install the dependencies from projects such as that one which has other dependencies defined in its environment.yml file?**

My question is similar to this one: [Conda importing one environment.yml into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158137/conda-importing-one-environment-yml-into-another).

Right now, I'm using option #1 of the most-voted answer given there: creating my environment and then updating it with the other project's environment. However, this is not ideal because it's only manually integrated and I feel this should be an automated process on conda's side.

Ideally, I would like to tell it something like "Hey, I want these dependencies and please check for their `environment.yml and requirements.txt` files for more dependencies" and let it work its magic as it usually does for dependencies with requirements.txt files.

Comment: Would solution #3 in that post be a possibility? Out of curiosity, what is the dependency?

Comment: Would it make sense to turn the subproject itself into a package? Standardizing the interface for declaring dependencies is one of the central problems that packaging infrastructure solves.